# Finding the real part of a complex function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I am trying to compute the real part of the following complex function:

$$S(z) = \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{z^{-\frac{1}{2}} + z^{-1}}\left(z + z^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

For context, this expression was obtained from the following ordinary differential equation

$$y'' + \left(1 + 2z^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)y' + \frac{1}{4}y = 0$$

for which I am trying to find the Stokes lines.

My first step is to obtain the controlling factor of the relevant leading behaviour. I assume, in the usual fashion, that $y(z) = e^{S(z)}$, from which I get the following equation in $S(z)$:

$$S''(z) + S'(z)^2 + \left(1 + 2z^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)S'(z) + \frac{1}{4} = 0$$

Assuming that the $S''(z)$ term becomes negligibly small for $|z| \to \infty$, we get the relation

$$S'(z)^2 + \left(1 + 2z^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)S'(z) + \frac{1}{4} = 0$$

This can be solved as a quadratic. I used Wolfram for the unpleasant integration. Taking the difference in the solutions, I get the above expression that I wish to take the real part of.

I am pretty much stuck though. Do I try and invoke Euler's formula? Perform some trick with the $z$'s?

Help or hints very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, that your differential equation is correct? Maybe there should be a multiplication instead of a summation between the last two terms.

Comment: Did you try transforming the expression like $\sqrt{z^{-\frac12}+z^{-1}}=\exp(\frac12\ln(\frac1{\sqrt{z}}+\frac1z))$
where $\ln : re^{i\theta} \mapsto \ln(r) + i\theta$ ?

Comment: Could you show the solution you obtained for the differential equation you gave ?

Comment: I misprinted the differential equation - has been corrected now to add the $y'$ term.